# IE 11, Flash, and HTML5 problems

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer-11

I have the latest version of flash running on Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 11. Unfortunately, when I try to view videos, be they mp4 files on my computer or embedded youtube videos, they are zoomed into the max. Yesterday adobe was not recognizing my flash player, despite reinstalling it just a few minutes prior. That forced me to reset my browser and restart my computer.

Now it recognizes that I have the latest version of flash installed, but I still have videos that are zoomed in all the way for an unknown reason. They look like this...

http://www.mediafire.com/view/65sohk8lfbtk0t4/zoomed%20in.PNG

[image]

When I go to youtube.com/html5 and request the html5 player, youtube videos do the same thing and look like this:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/w14ah8hbaajalqx/html5_zoomed.PNG

[image]

ActiveX filtering is also disabled. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this zoomed-in problem found on all your browsers (or just one specific browser)? If this problem affects even the desktop media players then check your graphics/GPU settings (in System settings)... Are you using a Windows PC? You should not need to restart the computer (and I doubt even browser, not with Chrome anyways). You should **always only** get any Flash Player updates from **[the Adobe site](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)** most other sites are just scams or virus installs.

Comment: Embedded videos seem to be working in chrome using the HTML5 player. I usually use Internet Explorer, which is where the problems have been. However, even Windows Media Player was zoomed in with downloaded videos on my computer. I am using Windows 7, and have only downloaded from Adobe's site to the best of my knowledge.